# Implementing Newtons method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use Newtons method to solve a Satellite Navigation problem, also I'm fairly new to programming.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ninjasoup\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Ninjasoup\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Ninjasoup/Desktop/MSc Space Science/SatNav AssignmentCode/SatNavCode1.3.py", line 72, in <module>
    fA = np.sqrt((x-xA)**2 + (y-yA)**2 + (z-zA)**2) - (dA-b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'type' and 'float'
```

I've tried changing the declaration of the unkown variables to different types but I keep getting the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from sympy import diff
#Constants
R = 6371
SD = 20200
c = 299792458

#Given Data
latA = 47.074834081442773
lonA = 18.487157448324282

latB = 17.949919573189003
lonB = 17.786195009535710

latC = 48.196896294687626
lonC = -67.929788607990332

latD = 77.374761092966111
lonD = -25.681600844602748


tofA = 0.070745909570054
tofB = 0.075407082536252
tofC = 0.074696101874954
tofD = 0.071921760657713

#Pseudo Range error
dA = c*tofA
dB = c*tofB
dC = c*tofC
dD = c*tofD

#Unknown Variables
x =float
y =float
z =float
b =float

#Coversion of Shperical to Cartesian Co-ordinates
xA = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latA)) * math.cos(math.radians(lonA))
yA = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latA)) * math.sin(math.radians(lonA))
zA = (R+SD) *math.sin(math.radians(latA))

xB = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latB)) * math.cos(math.radians(lonB))
yB = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latB)) * math.sin(math.radians(lonB))
zB = (R+SD) *math.sin(math.radians(latB))

xC = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latC)) * math.cos(math.radians(lonC))
yC = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latC)) * math.sin(math.radians(lonC))
zC = (R+SD) *math.sin(math.radians(latC))

xD = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latD)) * math.cos(math.radians(lonD))
yD = (R+SD) * math.cos(math.radians(latD)) * math.sin(math.radians(lonD))
zD = (R+SD) *math.sin(math.radians(latD))


#P1 = np.array([xA,yA,zA])
#P2 = np.array([xB,yB,zB])
#P3 = np.array([xC,yC,zC])
#P4 = np.array([xD,yD,zD])  
#print(P1,P2,P3,P4)


fA = np.sqrt((x-xA)**2 + (y-yA)**2 + (z-zA)**2) - (dA-b)
dfA1 = diff(fA, x)
dfA2 = diff(fA, y)
dfA3 = diff(fA, z)
dfA4 = diff(fA, b)

fB = np.sqrt((x-xB)**2 + (y-yB)**2 + (z-zB)**2) - (dB-b)
dfB1 = diff(fB, x)
dfB2 = diff(fB, y)
dfB3 = diff(fB, z)
dfB4 = diff(fB, b)

fC = np.sqrt((x-xC)**2 + (y-yC)**2 + (z-zC)**2) - (dC-b)
dfC1 = diff(fC, x)
dfC2 = diff(fC, y)
dfC3 = diff(fC, z)
dfC4 = diff(fC, b)

fD = np.sqrt((x-xD)**2 + (y-yD)**2 + (z-zD)**2) - (dD-b)
dfD1 = diff(fD, x)
dfD2 = diff(fD, y)
dfD3 = diff(fD, z)
dfD4 = diff(fD, b)

#Matrix of Partial derivatives (Jacobian)
J = [[dfA1,dfA2,dfA3,dfA4],
     [dfB1,dfB2,dfB3,dfB4],
     [dfC1,dfC2,dfC3,dfC4],
     [dfD1,dfD2,dfD3,dfD4]]

print(J)

#Matrix of functions   
F = [[fA],
     [fB],
     [fC],
     [fD]]

print(F)

#Guess Values
U = [[1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1]] 

#Evaluated values     
x,y,z,b = U - np.linalg.solve(J,F)

#Iteration 2..will do more iterations later.

U1 = [[x],
      [y],
      [z],
      [b]]

x1,y1,z1,b1 = U1 - np.linalg.solve(J,F)   

#Convert x,y,z back to spherical constants once code is working
```

Comment: Please read [this post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I see that the line defining `fA` in your question does not match the similar line in your code. Please run the actual code you show here and show the complete and exact traceback you get for the resulting error.

Comment: I just rearranged the fA slightly was all, also forgot to re run the code to get the correct error, full trace back now in op.

Comment: `x =float`... What do you expect this to do? Note: it does not initialize to zero

Comment: I thought that x=float would declare it as an unknown of type float until I could evaluate it...if I don't have it I get an 'x is undefined' error.

Comment: `x =float` sets x to be the same as the float function. You could now do `x('1.23')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `x=float` lines, it looks like you want to do **symbolic calculation**. Having "unknown variables" isn't possible with the basic python syntax (and in a large portion of progamming languages afaik) but the `sympy` package you're already using is meant just for that (you should probably check out the tutorial page [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#a-more-interesting-example)).

Here is how you would create symbolic variables (aka "unknow variables") :

```
from sympy import symbols
x, y, z, b = symbols('x y z b')
```

But once that's is done you will notice that your code break a bit further down the road when you try to use `np.linalg.solve`. The `numpy` module is only meant to operate on special objects called numpy arrays ,they are essentially N-dimentionnal matrices of numbers *aka "not symbolic expressions"*.

But `sympy` also has a solution to that problem : you can create matrices containing symbolic expressions and solve matricial equations too with ot . I'll just [link you to the tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html) so you can see how to properly define said matrices and how to use them.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks I knew what I wanted mathematically, just didn't know how to make python do it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize `x`, `y`, `z`, and `b` to actual floating values like `0.0`, not to `float`.

```
>>> 0.0   # a floating-point number
0.0
>>> float   # an object of class 'type' named 'float'
<class 'float'>
>>> x = float  # initialize to an object of class 'type'
>>> y = 0.0    # initialize to a floating number
>>> x
<class 'float'>
>>> y
0.0
>>> type(x)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(y)
<class 'float'>
```